# Condição em request laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Tenho uma classe de request chamada `PessoaRequest`. Nessa classe, faço a validação do meu formulário para cadastro de pessoas.

Mas agora, apareceram algumas informações para serem inseridas que não são obrigatórias: nome do pai e da mãe. Quando possuo essas informações, marco um `checkbox` que cria os campos html para inserir esses dados.

Na classe `PessoaRequest`, tenho as seguintes regras:

```
return [
      'name'       => 'required|min:3|alpha', //obrigatório com pelo menos 3 caracteres alfabéticos
      'telefone_1' => 'required',//obrigatório e deve ser um email
      'email'      => 'required'
      [....]
    ];
```

Nele ,não posso colocar regra para os campos que pedem nome do pai e da mãe , pois não obrigatórios.

Gostaria de saber se tem como colocar regra condicional dentro do `Request`, tipo :

```
// Se o checkbox for marcado
if($chkPais == 1 ) {
      'nome_pai' => 'required',
      'nome_mae' => 'required'
}
```

Caso não , como poderia fazer essa validação ?

Desde já , grato.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tem sim, eu costumo fazer muito isso no `Laravel 5`.

```
public function rules() 
{
    $rules = ['nome' => 'required', 'email' => 'required|email'];

    // Se o valor da checkbox for marcado

    if ($this->has('check_box'))
    {
         $rules['pai'] = 'required';
         $rules['mae'] = 'required';
    }


    return $rules;
}
```

Você só adiciona as validações de `pai` e `mae` se o valor do seu checkbox for marcado.

Apenas lembrando que quando criamos uma `Request`, estamos estendendo o `Request` padrão utilizado no `Laravel`. Então, através da pseudo variável `$this`, podemos acessar métodos como `get`, `has` e `only`.

O método `has` nesse caso serve para verificar se algum campo `check_box` foi enviado por um formulário. Se for vazio, `has` retornará `false`. Porém, se retornar algo, cairá no `if`, que adicionará à `$rules` os valors `pai` e `mae` para validação.

Comment: Boa tarde , obrigado pelo rápido retorno. Vou testar aqui e ja falo .

Comment: Boa tarde @Wallace , cara , deu certinho aqui. Quando der os 7min  ,marco como resolvido.  Vlw

Comment: Beleza, @HenriqueFelix. Que bom que isso ajudou. Não pensei que poderia te ajudar tão rápido :D

Comment: Então , estou um pouco atrasado para entregar essa pagina de cadastro com essa regra nova. Então , caiu como uma luva seu exemplo.